# Messy data on update pack layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to remove a circle and its subnodes from a pack layout and recalculate the others. I'm using `exit` to handle removed data, but whenever I add or remove an element and apply the transition, its context becomes messy:

[image: Example]

I can see that before `Erlang` was a `leaf`, and later it become the parent of `Clipper` and `Basic` (!?). Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/haskellcamargo/vuuazk0f/).

I've created a `pop` function that removes the **last** element:

```
window.pop = function() {
  data.children.pop();
  var selection = svg.datum(data).selectAll(".node").data(pack.nodes);

  // Removed nodes
  selection
    .exit()
    .remove();

  // Update it all
  selection
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return translate(d.x, d.y);
    })
    .select("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return d.r;
    });
};
```

And also an `update` function that adds an element.

I imagine that, if the text is having the behavior, it should be because the data got messy, because the text is **relatively** positioned. The poorly children are being lost from their parents! Why is this happening?

Comment: Use a key function for `.data()` https://jsfiddle.net/vuuazk0f/1/

Comment: You save my life. <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that D3 doesn't match the right data items with the right elements. You can tell it how to by providing a key function as the second argument to `.data()`:

```
var selection = svg.datum(data).selectAll(".node")
                   .data(pack.nodes, function(d) { return d.name; });
```

Complete demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vuuazk0f/1/).